How to remove the previous polylines after setting a new waypoint... Google Map with flutter
To clear previous polylines after setting a new waypoint on Google Maps with Flutter, you can follow these steps: first, maintain a reference to the previous polyline object. When adding a new waypoint, before adding the new polyline, remove the previous one using the `Polyline.remove()` method. This ensures that only the current route is displayed on the map at any given time, preventing clutter and confusion. By managing polyline references and removing them appropriately, you can maintain a clean and updated visualization of routes on Google Maps within your Flutter application.



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
